# Why I get the null pointer exception with the array?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
private static ArrayList<Countries> arr =null;
static String country;
static String capital;
static String cities;
static String answer;

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
    Scanner keybord = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Countries> d = read("data.txt");
    String res = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < d.size(); i++){
             res += d.get(i).toString();
        answer = keybord.nextLine();
        if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase(d.get(i).getCapital()))
            res+= "The answer is true!";
        else
            res += "The answer is not true" + "The answer is " + d.get(i).getCapital();
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}

public static ArrayList<Countries> read(String filename) throws IOException{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(filename));
    while(scan.hasNext()){
        country = scan.nextLine(); //System.out.println(country);
        String cities1 = scan.nextLine(); //System.out.println(cities1);
        String cities2 = scan.nextLine(); //System.out.println(cities2);
        String cities3 = scan.nextLine(); //System.out.println(cities3);
        String cities4 = scan.nextLine(); //System.out.println(cities4);
        String capital = scan.nextLine(); //System.out.println(capital);
        Countries c = new Countries(cities1, cities2, cities3, cities4, capital); 
        arr.add(c); // where i get the exception
        scan.nextLine();
    }
    return arr;
```

}

I could not understand why I'm getting the null pointer exception while I'm trying to add the countries to the array list? should not I instantiate it as a null before creating it?

Comment: Why is `arr` a static field and not just part of the scope of the `read` method?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't initialized `arr` so by default it is `null`

Initialize it by

```
private static ArrayList<Countries> arr = new ArrayList<Countries>();
```

**Also**,

You check if next element exist by

```
 while(scan.hasNext()){
```

and then you are reading next 7 line

```
country = scan.nextLine(); //System.out.println(country);
String cities1 = scan.nextLine(); //System.out.println(cities1);
String cities2 = scan.nextLine(); //System.out.println(cities2);
String cities3 = scan.nextLine(); //System.out.println(cities3);
String cities4 = scan.nextLine(); //System.out.println(cities4);
String capital = scan.nextLine(); //System.out.println(capital);

scan.nextLine();
```

Which can fail

Comment: Now in the top of the code I initialized it but there is still exception error?

Comment: Please post the updated code and the new exception stacktrace

Comment: How should I initialize the instance d for reading the data from the txt file?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1516)
 at Test.read(Test.java:41)
 at Test.main(Test.java:18)
it gives this and the line's are     String cities4 = scan.nextLine(); //System.out.println(cities4); and      ArrayList<Countries> d = read("data.txt");

Comment: From what I see you are using `scan.nextLine()` 7 times in your `read(String filename)`. Does your file contains multiplication of 7 lines (7,14,21,...)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize arr:

```
private static ArrayList<Countries> arr = new ArrayList<Countries>();
```

If you omit the `new ArrayList<Countries>();` part, the default value will be null, and then when you call `arr.add()`, you get that `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I made it now but there is still something like that. Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1516) at Test.read(Test.java:41) at Test.main(Test.java:18) first error is for this line String cities4 = scan.nextLine(); //System.out.println(cities4); the other one is ArrayList<Countries> d = read("data.txt");

Answer (score 0):

arr variable is not initialized, replace

```
private static ArrayList<Countries> arr
```

with

```
private static ArrayList<Countries> arr = new ArrayList<Countries>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You never initialized `arr`.

Add `arr = new ArrayList<Countries>();` to your `main`.